# How to get assignment of a reminder (EKReminder) in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit, ekreminder

[Update: I submitted an official Apple Developer feedback request for an update to the EventKit API and documentation]

[Update: I contacted Apple Support and they said to read the docs...so I think Matt is correct, It is simply not available.]

According to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekreminder), the EKReminder is a subclass of EKCalendarItem. It has the following (lot) of properties:

As a reminder:

- priority: Int - The reminder's priority.
- startDateComponents: DateComponents? - The start date of the task.
- dueDateComponents: DateComponents? - The date by which the reminder should be completed.
- isCompleted: Bool - A Boolean value determining whether or not the reminder is marked completed.
- completionDate: Date? The date on which the reminder was completed.

As a calendar item:

- title: String! -The title for the calendar item.
- location: String? - The location associated with the calendar item.
- creationDate: Date? - The date that this calendar item was created.
- lastModifiedDate: Date? - The date that the calendar item was last modified.
- timeZone: TimeZone? - The time zone for the calendar item.
- url: URL?
- hasNotes: Bool - A Boolean value that indicates whether the calendar item has notes.
- notes: String? - The notes associated with the calendar item.
- hasAttendees: Bool - A Boolean value that indicates whether the calendar item has attendees.
- attendees: [EKParticipant]? -The attendees associated with the calendar item, as an array of EKParticipant objects.

I can print any one of these items from reminders in my app.

However, if I create a reminder that is "assigned to a person", I cannot get that information. I know it must be stored somewhere.

If you "print" a reminder, you get something like this:

```
EKReminder <0x0000000> {title = Do the thing; dueDate = 2021-02-25 08:00:00 +0000; completionDate = (null); priority = 0; calendarItemIdentifier = XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX; alarms = (null)}
```

If you want, you can "print" any of the other items, like `print(reminder.notes!)`.

I thought shared items and assignments might use the `attendees` property, but it is nil - even when the reminder has an assigned person.

How can you get to the assigned person?

[image: Example of the Reminders App detail where Assign Person]

Comment: "if I create a reminder that is "assigned to a person"" That sounds cool. What's the user interface for doing that?

Comment: Hi, @matt - within the iOS Reminders app, when you click on the (i) in a reminder row, you can assign tasks to people in a shared List.  I'll add an image of that in the question. It only works on shared Lists (and "Lists" are really Calendars with a different name).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably a feature of upgraded reminders. But the API was never upgraded to match, so there’s no programmatic access to it.

Comment: I am not okay with this being the end. I've put in a developer ticket with Apple. We will see what I find out - fingers crossed it is something.

Comment: oh, I didn't vote you down, and I will not execute you.

Comment: @jessi did you ever hear back from Apple on this? I'm also trying to solve the same problem.

Comment: I never heard back from them @NathanHanna - Sorry it took so long to respond. I missed your comment.

Comment: Thanks @jessi, I ended up going straight to the sqlite database. It's a more fragile interface than I wanted but at least you can get the data there.